# Advantages and Disadvantages of static methods and functions

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that functions are independent from any class and *static methods* are attached to a class. It looks like both of them achieve the same. This leads me to the following question: What are the advantages and disadvantages of them?

I want to create set of functions for offline PIN configuration like `setPin`, `changePin`, `verifyPin`. Do I have to wrap them inside a class as static methods or can I just create them as functions in a Dart file?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members

Comment: @jamesdlin Is there a reason (performance, .. ) why you should not combine static functionality in one class. I think it makes sense for comprehensibility. Am I missing something?

Comment: @maxmitz There is no performance difference; `static` methods and functions are equivalent.  As explained by the Effective Dart guideline, using freestanding functions gives *callers* the freedom to choose what namespace to use for them.

Answer (score 7):

There are no **clear** "Advantages and Disadvantage" of static methods versus functions.

As you have correctly pointed out, the only **difference** is that static members are connected to a class.

```dart
class A {
  static bool b() => false;
}

bool c() => true;
```

The only difference here would be that you need to access the static member via `A.b` and `c` can be accessed directly.

Static methods are *not even inherited*, meaning that `class B extends A {}` will **not** allow you to use `B.b` because `b` is a static member **of** `A`.

Having said that, [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715) pointed out an article for writing good Dart design. [This article](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members) describes that you should avoid creating classes with only static members and calls it bad design, i.e. not idiomatic Dart:

> In idiomatic Dart, classes define kinds of objects. A type that is never instantiated is a code smell.

Coming back to your question, you should probably create your functions as top-level functions if they are not part of an object according to idiomatic Dart design based on the article from the Dart team.

However, you might consider changing the way you store your "PIN configuration" because this sounds like it would be ideal to store this information as an object.

Comment: Thanks. I am using [Flutter Secure Storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) and [Password Hashing](https://pub.dev/packages/password) to store and validate PIN

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree that just using classes with static methods is a bad design decision.
It enforces the OO principles but actually does not bring any benefit of OO.

If can not support inheritance and polymorphism then what is the point?
Functions on the other hand can bring more flexibility as dart supports standalone functions like javascript etc..

As an example lets look at a flutter class for creating a custom theme ..
This example is with a static getter..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTheme {
  static ThemeData get lightTheme {
    return ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
      errorColor: Colors.purple,
      textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
            headline6: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            button: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
      accentColor: Colors.indigo,
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        elevation: 12,
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
              headline6: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Bold',
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
              ),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Think about writing this with a function  like this..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

ThemeData myCustomLightTheme() {
  final ThemeData _lightTheme = ThemeData.light();

  final _appBarTheme = AppBarTheme(
    elevation: 12,
    textTheme: _lightTheme.textTheme.copyWith(
      headline6: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Bold',
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 18,
      ),
    ),
  );

  final _textTheme = _lightTheme.textTheme.copyWith(
    headline6: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    button: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 18,
    ),
  );

  return ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
      errorColor: Colors.purple,
      textTheme: _textTheme,
      accentColor: Colors.indigo,
      appBarTheme: _appBarTheme);
}
```